# one line copy constructor

Tags: c++, function, class

Going through how a copy constructor is created, I came across this example:

```
class MyClass 
{
      int x;
      char c;
      std::string s;
};
```

which is copied by the compiler as:

```
 MyClass::MyClass( const MyClass& other ) : x( other.x ), c( other.c ), s( other.s )
  {}
```

What is the meaning of `: x( other.x )...` in the same line as the function header line? How does it work?

Comment: only in constructors: initialize the variable x calling the specified constructor x(other.x) that is int(int). You should call the constructors in the same order you declared the variables in your class

Comment: The name of the feature is *member initializer list*, it's also called *mem-initializer-list* or sometimes just (confusingly) *initializer list*. Not to be confused with *braced initializer list* or `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructors "initialize" an object.  You're already familiar with using statements in the constructor body:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass& other) {
    x = other.x;
    c = other.c;
    s = other.s;
}
```

But before your constructor's body runs, all the members of the object must be initialized, meaning that their constructors run so that you can call their member functions (such as `operator=` as in the above example).  C++ gives you the opportunity to call the constructors explicitly, with the syntax you gave, in the so-called [*member initializer list*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).  (They will be called automatically by the compiler if you omit them.)  Note that I prefer the following formatting:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass& other)
    : x( other.x )
    , c( other.c )
    , s( other.s )
{}
```

What is happening is that the `x` (and `c` and `s`) constructors are called using the values in parentheses.  This is faster, because you're only doing one initialization, not two.  This might just seem like a nice convenience, but it is in fact necessary if you have `const` members.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation, regarding your last line, why is it necessary if I have `const` memebers?

Comment: Good question :).  It is necessary because `const` members are defined, roughly, as being unable to be changed after construction.  Your only chance to construct them is in the initializer list.